# Ionic 3 slide not working with autoplay

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3.

Here is my template

```
 <ion-slides autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="500" class="slides" pager="true">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let Image of PImage">
         <img src="{{Image.URL}}" alt="Product Image">
      </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined
```

How can I fix this issue?

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: Could you please try by adding a *ngif like this: `<ion-slides *ngIf="PImage && PImage.length" autoplay="5000"...>...</ion-slides>`? Seems like the issue may be related to the slides being created before the data is ready...

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.It's work fine.: )

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've added that as an answer with the link of one issue related to this :)

Comment: You can do like this way <ion-slides #slides *ngIf="sliderImages && sliderImages.length"  autoplay="3000" loop="true" speed="500" pager="true">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of sliderImages">
      <img src="{{item.image}}" alt="">
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10271) when trying to create the slides elements, when the data is not ready yet. To fix it, use an `*ngIf` to create the slides only when the data is ready:

```
<ion-slides *ngIf="PImage && PImage.length"  autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="500" class="slides" pager="true">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let Image of PImage">
         <img src="{{Image.URL}}" alt="Product Image">
      </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i  am facing an issue like when at first time when i load the page the slide are autoplaying but when i go the some page and comeback the this same page where slide are there it is not working that time.

Comment: man, i've been busting my chops on this for ages! the ngIf solution fixed it for me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If anyone use Ionic 4, then try this method:

HTML:

```
  <ion-slides #mySlider (ionSlidesDidLoad)="slidesDidLoad()" autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="500" class="slides" pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let adsImages of AdsImages">
      <img src="{{adsImages}}">
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

TS:

```
  AdsImages = [
    "../../assets/images/ads-sample.webp",
    "../../assets/images/ads-sample2.webp",
    "../../assets/images/ads-sample3.webp"
  ];

  slideOpts = {
    zoom: false
  };

  @ViewChild("mySlider") slides: IonSlides;

  slidesDidLoad() {
    this.slides.startAutoplay();
  }
```

SCSS:

```
ion-slides {
  --bullet-background: #ffffff;
  --bullet-background-active: #b8b8b8;
}
```

Fore more information: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides